# запуск страницы сайта на гитхаб

Tags: github, github-pages

загрузил свой проект на гитхаб, сначала идет содержимое папки с проектом, а в ней уже папка sourse в которой лежит страница, теперь гитхаб не может определить где находится файл index.html, как же сделать так что бы он его увидел?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: @nörbörnën таким примерно методом я и пользуюсь но это не помогает

Comment: Github pages находит index.html только если он в корне репозитория, или в папке docs, если выбрать эту папку в настройках. Перенести корень сайта в произвольную директорию репозитория не получится. Разве что настроить хитрый github action, который будет деплоить сайт в отдельную ветку в корень, и на эту ветку настроить github pages.

Comment: @insolor всё так и выходит